# How do I retrieve the values of selected checkboxes and show it in the template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

***What am I doing ?***
I'm training on a simple application where one can order a pizza and select his toppings, once the form submitted it shows the submitted queries in the template file.

***What is the problem?***
I'm having a really hard time showing the checked checkboxes from the form on the template file.

[image]

Here are my files :

**models.py**

```
class PickedDatas(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Picked(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    picked = models.ManyToManyField(PickedDatas, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('%s' % (obj.name))

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picked
        fields = ['name', 'picked']

    picked = CustomChoiceField(queryset=PickedDatas.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

**views.py**

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        form = SomeForm

    return render(request, 'features.html', {'form':form, 'picked':Picked.objects.all()})
```

As for the template file, I'm using the for loop to show Picked models datas.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do ?

---

EDIT

here is the template file **features.html**

```
<h2>Enter your name and choose your pizza toppings</h2>
                        <form method='post'>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.as_p }}
                            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
                        </form>
                        {% for p in picked %}
                            <h2>Pizza For : <strong>{{ p.name }}</strong></h2>
                            <p>{{ p.picked }}</p>
                        {% endfor %}
```

it gives me this for {{ p.picked }} : pizza.PickedDatas.None

Comment: Since your question is about the template, shouldn't you *show that template*?

Comment: @DanielRoseman here is the template file, I just didn't put it since I have no idea what to do to access the selected checkboxes values only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Picked.picked` is a many to many field, so you need to loop through the options:

```
{% for picked in picked %}<!-- Note renamed variable to prevent clash with inner loop -->
  <h2>Pizza For : <strong>{{ picked.name }}</strong></h2>
  <p>{% for p in picked.picked.all %}{{ p }}{% endfor %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```